# Apache Camel - war project How to process the Queue and set to another queue?

Tags: apache-camel

I set the Pojo Object to the Queue (From the standalone application) which is in the war and then withing the war I need to read from the Queue and process the Object. Once that is done that Object set to another Queue (Processed Queue). All the processing happening withing the war. So there will be an another application which reads from the processed queue and process the object.

So what is the best way to handle this scenario? Is there any end to end sample which I can get?

Comment: that is certainly not overkill, as reading and writing to JMS queues is not easy and you need to write code. With Camel that can be done purely in XML or much easier in code with few lines of code.

Comment: Hi Claus Ibsen, Thanks for ur comments and could you please let me know how to handle the above scenario? What is the best way to handle this? Is there any end to end sample I can get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use an external JMS broker (ActiveMQ) and each application can connect to this broker independently and produce/consume from queues....this is a standard/lightweight way to bridge applications with JMS...

```
<!--APP1-->
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
   <from uri="activemq:inQ" />
   <to uri="bean:MyBean" />    
   <to uri="activemq:outQ" />
  </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://somehost:61616"/>
</bean>

<!--APP2-->
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
   <from uri="activemq:outQ" />
   ...
  </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://somehost:61616"/>
</bean>
```

see this page for more details: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Comment: Hi boday, Why do you recommend to use use an external JMS broker as withing camel itself I could configure the same right? And also how Can I achieve this with the Java DSL without doing on XML configuration with Spring? Also could you publish the Java DSL sample please?

Comment: Also I have tried the above example. Unfortunately that doesnt work the way I want. When I set my bean to the inQ it shows that processed but it doesn't goes to the outQ. Any idea?

Comment: I suggested the external broker because you have 2 apps...otherwise, yes you could use an embedded broker, but then when app1 is down, app2 could not process the Q, etc....otherwise, you just need to make sure your bean returns the processed result so its added to the Exchange going to the outQ (need to make sure its serializable as well)